# Timing out when I use a proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to implement proxies into my web crawler. Without the proxies, my code has no problem connecting to the website, however when I try to add in proxies, suddenly it won't connect! It doesn't look like anybody in python-requests has made a post about this problem, so I'm hoping you all can help me!

Background info: I'm using a Mac and using Anaconda's Python 3.4 inside of a virtual environment.

Here is my code that works without proxies

```
proxyDict = {'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128'}

def pmc_spider(max_pages, pmid): 
    start = 1

    titles_list = []
    url_list = []
    url_keys = []

    while start <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmid/'+str(pmid)+'/citedby/?page='+str(start)

        req = requests.get(url) #this works
        plain_text = req.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")

        for items in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'title'}):
            title = items.get_text()
            titles_list.append(title)

            for link in items.findAll('a'):
                urlkey = link.get('href')
                url_keys.append(urlkey)   #url = base + key
                url =  "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"+str(urlkey)
                url_list.append(url)

        start += 1
    return titles_list, url_list, authors_list
```

Based on other posts I'm looking at, I should just be able to replace this:

```
req = requests.get(url)
```

with this:

```
req = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict, timeout=2)
```

But this doesn't work! :( If I run it with this line of code the terminal gives me a TimeOut error

```
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 362, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1137, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 963, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 898, in send
self.connect()
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 167, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 147, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.timeout))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError:       (<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1052665f8>, 'Connection to 10.10.1.10 timed out. (connect timeout=2)')
```

And then I get a few of these printed in the terminal with different traces but the same error:

```
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 403, in send
timeout=timeout
 File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/Users/hclent/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 281, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.10.1.10', port=3128): Max retries exceeded with url: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmid/18269575/citedby/?page=1 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1052665f8>, 'Connection to 10.10.1.10 timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))
```

Why would the addition of proxies to my code suddenly cause me to timeout? I tried it on several random urls and had the same thing happen. So it seems to be a problem with proxies rather than a problem with my code. However, I'm at the point where I MUST use proxies now so I need to get to the root of this and fix it. I've also tried several different IP addresses for the proxy from a VPN that I use, so I know the IP addresses are valid.

I appreciate your help so much! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried extending the timeout beyond 2 seconds?
it's likely that the traffic flow through the proxy may take longer than that to return, which will give you the error you see

Comment: @KerryM-R if I change it to 20 seconds it still times out just the same. How long are you thinking?

Comment: That should be long enough, have you confirmed that the proxy (10.10.1.10) is responding correctly?

Comment: @KerryM-R I actually have no idea how to do that? I took that proxy off of a post on stack overflow actually, but all other proxy IP address that I've used also haven't worked. A 'proxy' in this case is just an IP address, no?

Comment: Ahh, in that case that 10.10.1.10 probably just comes from the requests documentation here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

As it's just acting as a http proxy you should be able to test connection to it using a browser, just use the same details and see if it's operational

Comment: @KerryM-R In that case, it looks like I cant use any of the IP address proxies I have?! None of them are connecting in the browser. Where do I go from here? Try random IPs or? It looks like requests/socks requires that you know which proxies to use.

Comment: After a cursory search for free proxies there's a list here: http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/

not sure of the security of these, but without setting up your own, or paying for one they might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to use a http or https proxy that will respond to requests.

The `10.10.1.10:3128` in your code seems to be from examples in the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies%20As%20it')

Taking a proxy from the list at http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/search-1291967 (may not be the best source) your proxyDict should look like this: `{'http' : 'http://209.242.141.60:8080'}`

testing this on the command line seems to work fine:

```
>>> proxies = {'http' : 'http://209.242.141.60:8080'}
>>> requests.get('http://google.com', proxies=proxies)
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: This worked! Although when I put that proxy into my web browser it takes me to some login page. Is that should I should normally expect when verifying that a proxy works? Thank you so much!

Comment: As long as it's either redirecting your traffic to somewhere else (this might be undesireable), or your IP shows differently when you [google what's my ip](https://www.google.com.au/?ion=1&espv=2#q=what%20is%20my%20ip) the proxy should be working.

In the log run it's probably best to either setup your own proxy, or use a paid one